# JavaScript: Non-standard ways to convert characters to codes, or strings to binary arrays (arrays of numbers)

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, binary, character

Is there a trick in JavaScript to convert character to it's code, other than .charCodeAt(i)?
I want to convert string to binary array by a fastest way (i.e. faster than charCodeAt can do it).
But I also interested to know about slow methods too.

Comment: 1) there are many binary representations for a string. which one do you want? 2) what's a JS binary array?

Comment: I mean the array of numbers (the array with codes of chars)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a lookup table, but I doubt that it would be any faster. Something like:

```
function(str){
    var codes = {},
        output = [];

    for (var i=0; i<256; i++){
        String.codes[fromCharCode(i)] = i;
    }

    for (var i=0; i<str.length; i++){
        output.push(codes[str[i]]);
    }

     return output;
}
```

Generally speaking though if you can go with native code, go with native code.

Comment: Yep, just made a quick test and using charCodeAt is 2 - 3 times faster.

Comment: hobberwickey, I suspected that. But in any case this is an alternative to charCodeAt. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you will find something faster than this code to accomplish what you want:

```
function getCharArray(str)
{
    var chars = [];
    for (var i = 0, n = str.length; i != n; ++i) {
        chars.push(str.charCodeAt(i));
    }
    return chars;
}
```

You have to do it this way because JavaScript doesn't have a separate type for a single character; even a single character is still a string and therefore you need `String.charCodeAt()`.

Comment: I'm search NOT charCodeAt solution (it is clearly described in the question).

Comment: @Poch and I'm saying there's no such thing.

Answer (score 0):

Strings in javascript are unicode, not ascii, meaning that the code of a single character might be more than one byte.

```
"€".charCodeAt(1) = 8364
```

This fits into two bytes. If you convert it back to binary it could be interpreted as either one 2-byte-character or 2 1-byte-characters. There is just no way to know. Knowing the length of a unicode char is tricky. This might help you see why this problem is hard to solve: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Of course I'm not saying you can't convert unicode strings to binary, I'm stating that this is the task you need to solve, not just converting single characters to bytes.

Comment: And sometimes a character can be more than two bytes. But we can assume that a string is a simple unicode string with 32-bit characters (0..65535), which should be converted to 32-bit unsigned integers (to a binary representation).